# PowerShell Copy-Item: The System detected a possible attempt to compromise security

Tags: powershell, security, ioexception, copy-item

I am trying to copy files from local computer to remote computer.

Here is my  code

```
$localPath='D:\Apps\temp.txt'
$remoteComputerLocation='\\192.168.1.200\E$\tempfolder'
Copy-Item $localPath -Destination $remoteComputerLocation -Force
```

So when i try to run this i got this error

> Copy-Item: The System detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you. At line:3 char 1
> Copy-Item $localPath -Destination $remoteComputerLocation -Force
> +CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
> +FullyQualifiedErrorID : System.IO.IOException, Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.CopyItemCommand.

I am using this to copy files from local computer to remote computer. I have also used **-Credential** parameter.

Comment: Could be a Windows [Update issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3178465) when failing back to NTLM. Anyway, that's not a programming issue, so try SuperUser instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. vonPryz. 
When I use super user, which is administrator, it works fine. But problem occurs when i try with domain account.

Comment: This error is passed from Windows. In other words, I don't think it is a PowerShell issue. What happens when you try this from the command (`cmd`) prompt?

Comment: That "SuperUser" would be [superuser.com](https://superuser.com), a site in Stack Exchange network that's about general computing and configuration issues.